# how can i change the help button function at error in runtime in vb6?

Tags: vb6

I want to change the procedure of the help button in runtime error how can I achieve that
Explanation:
I want when I press on the Help Button Open Message box instead of Help.
[image]

Comment: Is that window generated by the IDE itself? Or is it a custom window?

Comment: Since that is the standard error handler for VB6, there would be no simple way to re-purpose the button.  However, there are solutions such as this question/answer which lists a solution from "Everything Access" which can create a global error handler so you could simply raise your own message entirely when it is triggered.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65020/is-there-a-way-to-add-global-error-handler-in-a-visual-basic-6-0-application#:~:text=With%20%22SimplyVB6%20Global%20Error%20Handler,and%20you%20are%20all%20set.